# How to create an int named "int" in Java

Tags: java, eclipse, int, instance, instantiation

Well, as title says it is a weird question. I want to create an int called int and of course if i write;

```
int int;
```

java(eclipse) gives error. So I've been wondering if it is possible to create such a thing? if you are asking me why i insist on this, I've created str for strength, agi for agility, but int for intelligence can not be created. So should I just describe it in another way or is there a simple way to do it?

Comment: Call it smth like `_int` or `int_`

Comment: Or `Int`, `intel`, even `intelligence`. ;) It is not a good idea to confuse others with keyword-like abbreviations. It is good imho that it cannot be used as a variable name.

Comment: Probably don't call it `Int` -- that goes against Java naming conventions (looks like a class name). Even `_int` or `int_` is a bit sketchy. I would go for `intelligence`, myself.

Comment: 'intl' should be more perfect

Answer (score 8):

The identifier `int` is a reserved keyword in Java and cannot be used as a variable name.

I would suggest *not* abbreviating your attributes, but instead use full words:

```
int strength;
int agility;
int intelligence;
```

Even if there were a way to create a variable named `int`, the resulting code would be confusing to read later.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. `int` isn't a valid identifier in Java, because it's a keyword.

From [JLS 3.8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.8):

> An identifier cannot have the same spelling (Unicode character sequence) as a keyword (§3.9), boolean literal (§3.10.3), or the null literal (§3.10.7), or a compile-time error occurs.

Compare this with `str`, which isn't a keyword. (And neither is `String`, in fact.)

As Greg says, it's clearer to use full names (`strength`, `intelligence` etc) anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that. It's a reserved word.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't, because it is keyword, i.e. reserved word in `Java`. Call it smth like `_int` or `int_`

Answer (score 0):

It is a [reserved word](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reserved_word). You can not use it as an identifier.